# Create a bootable Debian USB stick for PowerPC from Windows

Tags: debian, powerpc

I recently installed an SSD into my iBook G4, and I'm gonna try to put Debian 8.2.0 on it via USB stick. I know to how to trick Open Firmware into booting from USB, however, I need to create my USB stick from within Windows. How do I make a USB stick for PowerPC on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Rufus can do your job if you want create a Bootable USB Stick. https://rufus.akeo.ie/